# What is the difference between SharePoint 2013 groups and roles?

Tags: sharepoint-server, permissions, groups, roles

I'm in the process of setting up a SharePoint 2013 server with user groups, permissions, etc., and I am confused about the difference between SharePoint user roles, and SharePoint user groups.

Basically I'd like to be able to control files and folders so only certain users see certain content. What would be the best way to accomplish that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'd like to be able to control files and folders so only certain users see certain content. What would be the best way to accomplish that?**

- You can do this by sharing  a specific files to a specific people as the following

[image]

- Then assign `View Only`

[image]

**What is the difference between SharePoint 2013 groups and roles?**

- `Role` is the Permission Level like Contribute role , the Read role  Design role, Full Control role ... etc
- `Group` is a collection of users that have specific permission role.

**For Example :**

you can see by default a Visitor group that mean I have a group called visitor with `Read Role`. and By default, SharePoint includes the following predefined user roles:

- Visitor   Has read privileges.
- Member   Has read and contribute privileges.
- Owner   Has administrator privileges.

You can also build your `custom role or (Permission level)` and assign it to your custom group based on your requirement by doing the following

- At the Site Collection > Go to Site Settings > Site permissions > from the above ribbon  Permission Level .

[image]

- Click Add Permission Level with your required permission (Read Items)

[image]

- Now create your group with this new custom Permission Level.
- Add the users to this group > Add this group to your List Permission